# how to get elements in sub-array of a numpy array in python

Tags: python, numpy, sub-array

I'm getting in trouble with reading the entries of a sub-array of a numpy array, in python. I've got something like this:

```
a = np.array([ [453,254,[1,2,3,4,5]], [743,251,[10,20,30,40,50]], [127,393,[11,22,33,44,55]] ], dtype=object)
```

and I need to calculate the average value of each nth column of the 2nd-position sub-array, i.e. `np.mean([1,10,11]), np.mean([2,20,22])`, etc.

How can I get the `[1,10,11], [2,20,22]`, etc. sub-arrays?

I've tried different combinations with `":"` and `","` but I can't figure it out. I also put `dtype=object` in the numpy array definition, but it doesn't make any difference. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `np.array(a[:,2].tolist()).mean(1)`? Perhaps it would be more convenient in the long run to split your array in two.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
np.mean([x[0] for x in a[:,2]])
np.mean([x[1] for x in a[:,2]])
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a possible solution using

```
np.dstack((a[:,2]))[0][0]
```